# Vim - How to enter commands in "behave mswin" mode?

Tags: vim

How to enter command mode in gVim with these settings:

> set nocompatible
>   source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be altering Vim's behavior so much that you cannot enter commands the same way you would without sourcing that file.

Comment: Command which causes the problem was "set im!". It's necessary to place :start in the beginning of _vimrc instead of that command. More info: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Start_in_insert_mode_without_losing_your_escape_key

Comment: How did you get "set im!" your mswin.vim file? Or did you somehow get it in your vimrc?

Comment: Yes, in vimrc. My fault, I didn't listed all settings.